# How to align caption below each photo?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to do a photo gallery when user can upload photos and display them. Multiple photos display in the same line but I want to add a caption under each and I can't manage it. Can someone help me with this?

Here's my HTML/PHP code:
$image_path is an uploaded photo and basename($image_path) is a caption

```css
.container .gallery a img {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 20%;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .15s ease;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform .15s ease;
  -o-transition: -o-transform .15s ease;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform .15s ease;
  transition: transform .15s ease;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <a href="<?= $image_path; ?>">
<img src="<?= $image_path; ?>">
</a>
  <?=basename($image_path)?>
</div>
```

Comment: try wrapping the `basename($image_path)` in an `h3` element and style it with `text-align: center;`

Comment: @RamondeVries it doesn't work because then photos aren't inline but like stepped? and captions are chaotic scattered between them :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add :

```
.container .gallery {
    width: 20%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}
```

and replace `float:left;` to `float:none;`& `width:100%;` in `.container .gallery a img`

Comment: thank you so much!! it worked like a charm. but now one little problem - if the caption is long it overlays the next one. how to resolve it? I assume bigger distance between images won't work so maybe make it move to another line?

Comment: Ok , i got it , try to add overflow: hidden; margin: auto; width: 85%; to caption , and tell me if it work correctly

Comment: yes it works :) and also when I simply pack caption in a div it looks good. thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this, it isn't ?

```css
figure {
    padding: 5px;
    max-width: 150px;
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}

figcaption {
    background-color: #222;
    color: #fff;
    font: italic smaller sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
<figure>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
         alt="Elephant at sunset"></a>
    <figcaption>An elephant at sunset</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
         alt="Elephant at sunset"></a>
    <figcaption>An elephant at sunset</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
         alt="Elephant at sunset"></a>
    <figcaption>An elephant at sunset</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
         alt="Elephant at sunset"></a>
    <figcaption>An elephant at sunset</figcaption>
</figure>
<figure>
    <a href="#">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
         alt="Elephant at sunset"></a>
    <figcaption>An elephant at sunset</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this and photos were under each other and captions next to them

Answer (score 0):

Add one div for `basename` and try to apply this css into it.

```css
.basename {
      top: 90%;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="basename"><?=basename($image_path)?></div>
```

Comment: thank you but now all captions are at the bottom aligned on each other :(